# What login did a person get authenticated under?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have a new intern and he is able to log into our dev environment.  However, I can't figure out how.  We have AD Security Groups as our Logins in SQL Server.  After a lot of research with our server guys we figured out that the intern group is part of the local admin group on our development servers.  The local admin group has a login to SQL Server and that is how he was able to get in.  This brought about the following question.

In SQL Server is there a way to tell what login a person is authenticated under?

**Scenario:**

```
Domain = ACME

User = Bob

Bob is in the AD group ACME\IT-Dept

SQL Server has a login for ACME\IT-Dept
```

How can I tell that Bob was allowed in via the login for ACME\IT-Dept without knowing that Bob is in that group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo can find it out in following ways:

1. By impersonating that login and querying sys.login_token like this:

   ```
   execute as login = 'that_login';

   select distinct name, type
   from sys.login_token
   where principal_id > 0
         and type in ('WINDOWS LOGIN', 'WINDOWS GROUP');

   revert;
   ```
2. Looking at the permission path:

   ```
    exec xp_logininfo 'that_login', 'all';
   ```

I prefer the first one as more reliable

Comment: That is sweet.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Just to be clear, there may be *more than one* group that the user qualifies for. Their individual permissions are the union of all of the group permissions for groups that they're in.